# Synchronizing two (VM) Linux systems

Tags: linux, virtual-machine, sync, arch-linux

I have on my laptop and desktop two virtual Arch Linux (Colinux) installations, I want them to have the same set of software installed and configuration. How can I easily keep them in sync?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like something you could do with [rsync](http://www.samba.org/rsync/).

Comment: You think I should just use rsync with whole Linux filesystem? Will it be smart enough to not send too much?

Comment: Yep. Rsync will only update what it needs to mirror the system. You can iron out a good set by selectively `--exclude`ing things you would not want to sync, such as `/mnt`